# Refactor nested subscribe with conditional rxjs6

Tags: typescript, rxjs, angular7

I'm aware that nested subscribes is not recommended but I can't find any good resources on refactoring them.

This is my code as it stands:

```
this.checkExists(request.id).subscribe(exists => {
  if (exists) {
    this.getDeleteReason(request.id).subscribe(reason => {
      if (reason) {
        this.checkExists(request.id).subscribe(exists2 => {
          if (exists2) {
            // DO DELETE
          }
        });
      }
    });
  }
});
```

I've tried playing around with mergeMap but keep getting tied in knots.

Could someone please point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Combination of `filter` and `mergeMap`/`switchMap`.

```
 this.checkExists(request.id).pipe(
    filter(exists => exists),
    mergeMap(() => this.getDeleteReason(request.id)),
    filter(reason => reason),
    mergeMap(() => this.checkExists(request.id)),
    filter(exist2 => exist2)
  }).subscribe(() => {
      //do delete
  });
```

EDITED:
There are ways to pass `reason` into subscribe. In this particular case I would add `reason` next to `exist2`.

```
this.checkExists(request.id).pipe(
    filter(exists => exists),
    mergeMap(() => this.getDeleteReason(request.id)),
    filter(reason => reason),
    mergeMap(reason => ({
             exist2: this.checkExists(request.id), 
             reason})),
    filter(({exist2}) => exist2)
  }).subscribe(({reason}) => {
      //do delete
  });
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I should have mentioned that I need the "reason" field available in the final subscribe.

Without having a variable which is set on the outer scope, how can I pass that all the way through?

Comment: @shavenwalrus I added edit answer to include an answer to your question.

Comment: for me this one is best and more elegant approch to your question, thanks you for sharing.

Answer (score 0):

If they are three seperate tasks/observables, then consider to use `forkJoin`

```
let observable1(param1);
let observable2(param2);
let observable3(param3);

let joinedObservables = forkJoin(observable1, observable2, observable3).subscribe(x => {
  let result1 = x[0];
  let result2 = x[1];
  let result3 = x[2];

  ...
});
```

If their results depends on each other you can use `switchMap`, `flatMap`, `mergeMap`, `exhaustMap` (check differences)

```
let resultObservable =  return this.observable1().pipe(mergeMap((param1) => {
  return this.observable2().pipe(map((param1) => {

    ....        

    return <result>;
  }));
}));

resultObservable.subscribe(x => {
   ...
});
```

Comment: Yeah, forkJoin is no good, I don't want them to run at the same time.

I understand the mergeMap approach but what I'm not sure about is the conditionals. If you look at my post there are a couple of instances (checkExists) where I only want to proceed if the value is true.

Comment: you can put conditions inside switchMap. use it just like .subscribe, just you need to return result at the end of the switchMap function.